# Custom DNS in dd-wrt

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, router

We're doing development on a remote server that only listens on internal IPs. We VPN into the remote network, and then use custom hosts files to test what we're doing in the browser.

Now we're working on a mobile interface, and would like to test from non-rooted mobile devices. We can make our dev servers listen on public IPs, however without modifying the hosts file on the devices themselves, we have no way to tell them to resolve our private domains to the IPs of our choice.

is there any way to configure our router which is running dd-wrt to resolve our private domain names to the IPs of our choice?

Comment: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DNSMasq_Local_Network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In DD-WRT, go to Services->DNSMasq (Enable)

In the DNSMasq box, enter each hostname in the following format, one per line:

```
address=/localhost/127.0.0.1
```

After applying settings, and if DNS is not cached, you should be able to resolve the new names.

Comment: Great, that worked!